# Geofencing Push Message when App is Force-Closed

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

Does anyone know if a geofencing push notification can be delivered to a customer from SFMC even if they have force-closed the app?

Comment: Are you experiencing an instance where you are not receiving a message when the app is force closed?

Comment: I'm trying to convince our app team that they should be using SFMC for push notifications and not trying to build their own push platform from scratch. One of their questions was this one about geofencing.  If the app is not running at all, not even in the background, could a geofence message still get pushed? would SFMC somehow be able to tell where the device is at even if the app is not running (but installed, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If implemented correctly, yes, the SDK will show geofence (and any other Marketing Cloud related messaging) whether the SDK is running or not.

I say, "If implemented correctly" because the SDK *must* be initialized in the Application's Application Class' `onCreate()` method.  When the geofence is broken Google Play Services will broadcast an intent that is picked up by the SDK's receiver.  If the application is not running, the receipt of this broadcast will start it resulting in the SDK being initialized and the notification message being shown.